# get table name from count query

Tags: php, mysqli

How do you get table name from count query, I have multiple queries and I need to get table name from the query results, here is my query

```
$myquery = "select count(tb_id) as num_rows from table1; select count(tb1_id) from table2...";
if (myqli_multi_query($connection, $myquery){
..
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$num_rows = $row["num_rows"];
..
}
```

The query is working fine as I can get the number of rows, but I am unable to link the table name to the number of rows (result)

I have tried this, which executes without error, but unable to get the table name still

```
select count(tb_id) as num_rows, 'table1' as TableName from table1
```

Comment: Surely you know the table name as you are querying it?

Comment: I have about 20 tables and I am running a multi_query on all the tables, when I get the results from the multi_query it returns num of rows only, so I am unable to verify for which table it is for. So I wanted to have the table name return with the number of rows for each table.

Comment: consider looking at:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html. If I understand you correctly this is what you need.

Comment: Ah... The both of the solutions below will work for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put an identifier into your query you can refer to later.

```
$myquery = "select 'table1' as tablename, count(tb_id) as num_rows from table1; 
select 'table2' as tablename, count(tb1_id) as num_rows from table2;"
// and so on
```

Comment: I can get num_rows but tablename is still not on the result, I am using mysqli_fetch_assoc($result), here is my result mysqli_result **Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 2 [lengths] => Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => 1 ) [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 )** from one row, no tablename

Comment: **Array ( [tablename] => careers [num_rows] => 3 )** from 'mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);' Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just add it in to the select or the column name.

Column name:

```
select count(tb_id) as table1_count from table1; select count(tb1_id) as table2_count from table2.
```

OR sep column:

```
(select count(tb_id) as num_rows, 'table1' as tablename from table1)
UNION
(select count(tb1_id), 'table2' from table2...)
UNION.... etc
```

Edited to add: you are returning sep resultsets; consider UNION above for a single resultset.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`mysqli_fetch_field`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php)

```
mysqli_fetch_field($result)->table;
```